# What does CPU_USER in information_schema.profiling mean

Tags: mysql, oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have a query which is joining 10+ tables to create another table. I will need to create multiple tables simultaneously by running the same queries, so each connection would read from these tables. And I notice that my performance is not gained linearly hence I do a profiling on this and notice that the CPU_USER value in the information_schema.profiling table is unreasonable large.
Anyone could help to explain what is this CPU_USER and why it is large when I run multiple threads at the same time?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [User CPU time vs System CPU time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310039/user-cpu-time-vs-system-cpu-time)

Comment: hmm... It does't look like time though. eg. my query took 100s to finish and the in the duration it shows 100 but the value of CPU_USER is 800+