# How does Firebase Performance Monitoring SDK discover CPU usage of Android application?

Tags: android, firebase, cpu-usage, power-management, firebase-performance

As you can see in the picture below, with Firebase Monitoring SDK you can discover how much user time and system time your app consumes. [Check it here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/get-started-android)

[image]
The picture is for an iPhone device, but the document says Android devices are supported too.

So I'm sure there is a way to get this data programmatically as Firebase does. I want to know how does Firebase discover this information.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to calculate the CPU usage of a process by PID is to parse the `/proc/[pid]/stat` file. According to the [doc](https://linux.die.net/man/5/proc), the `/proc/[pid]/stat` file contains status information about the process. So we can parse this file to get the following members:

- utime %lu
- stime %lu

[Check this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420426/how-to-calculate-the-cpu-usage-of-a-process-by-pid-in-linux-from-c) to get more information about the `/proc/[pid]/stat` file and the way to [parse it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4410209/8460132).

Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310039/user-cpu-time-vs-system-cpu-time) is a relevant question about `utime` and `stime`.

I'm not sure whether Firebase is doing this. But this is a good way to get that information if and only if the `/proc/[pid]/stat` file is present and accessible in all Android versions.

**See also**

> [How do I get the total CPU usage of an application from /proc/pid/stat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16726779/how-do-i-get-the-total-cpu-usage-of-an-application-from-proc-pid-stat)
>
> [How to get total cpu usage in Linux using C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017162/how-to-get-total-cpu-usage-in-linux-using-c)